# Heading underlined in info files on macOS (railwaycat)

Tags: osx, info

I recently installed railwaycat's [Emacs Mac Port](https://github.com/railwaycat/homebrew-emacsmacport), and found that, unlike [Emacs for Mac OS X](https://emacsformacosx.com), the headings in info files are now underlined.

How can I get rid of these superfluous underlines?

The image below illustrates the issue, as it appears in Emacs 26.1 (build 1, x86_64-apple-darwin17.6.0, Carbon Version 158 AppKit 1561.4).

[image]

:

Answer (score 1):

This bug has been fixed in the release [emacs-26.1-mac-7.2](https://bitbucket.org/mituharu/emacs-mac/commits/tag/emacs-26.1-mac-7.2) (see [NEWS-mac](https://bitbucket.org/mituharu/emacs-mac/src/7fdbfba85d543f01b81e997e2b03788c35cb3bfa/NEWS-mac?at=emacs-26.1-mac-7.2&fileviewer=file-view-default)).